# a conjunction "when" and tense around it with "can"

Tags: word-request, tense, conjunctions

How can I describe this situation?:

Can I say the following sentence:

> I'm really glad **when I can** take a good picture.

I have heard that "can" may have several meanings. The sentence I wrote above seems to me as if it's describing an occasion when I get permission to take good pictures, but I am trying to convey "I'm really glad every time I succeed in taking a good picture." How can I convey that while using "when" and "can"?

I also get confused about tenses while using "when".

Can I say the following sentence:

> I'm really glad **when I have been** able to take a good picture

Or are there more natural expressions?

Comment: You're right about the multiple senses of "can." Your rewrite is fine, but it would also be okay to put it in the present tense: "I'm really glad when I'm able to take a good picture."

Comment: @AndyBonner Oh, I see!  I didn't know my rewrite was also OK.  So, "be able to" is good here!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Your original sounds fine to me - without any further context, I assumed "can" to mean exactly what you described - "succeed in".

Comment: @cruthers Oh, really, I see!  Thank you very much for your useful information. So, if there isn't confusing context, both "can" and "be able" OK? I see, thank you!

Comment: Yes, both are fine, and I might further recommend "get" as a potentially more colloquial-sounding word - "I'm really glad when I can get a good picture" would be a pretty common way of saying it (assuming, again, there is no confusing context that would suggest "get" means "receive from someone").

Comment: @cruthers Oh, your variation really matches! I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: I agree with the comments above. If you want the second sentence to sound a bit more "natural" (which I'm interpreting as "colloquial"), you might use a second contraction: "I'm really glad when I've been able to take a good picture."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Ah, I see.  Is it because I say "I'm" in a casual way? Thank you very much! I understand.